# Change the name Category - Not change category name

Tags: categories

My client has a Law Firm, and he is asking if we can change the term *CATEGORIES* to *JURISDICTION*. (I tried to explain that he could create a new category called "jurisdiction", but that is not an option)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `taxonomy_labels_category` filter (documented here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_labels_taxonomy/) in order to change any of the labels that you need changed.

Here's what works for me:

```
add_filter( 'taxonomy_labels_category', 'filter_category_labels' );
function filter_category_labels( $labels ) {
    $labels->menu_name = 'Jurisdiction';
    return $labels;
}
```

You will have to change quite a few other values in the $labels object though.

Here's a full list of the properties of the object:

- name
- singular_name
- search_items
- popular_items
- all_items
- parent_item
- parent_item_colon
- edit_item
- view_item
- update_item
- add_new_item
- new_item_name
- separate_items_with_commas
- add_or_remove_items
- choose_from_most_used
- not_found
- no_terms
- items_list_navigation
- items_lists
- most_used
- back_to_items
- menu_name
- name_admin_bar